# error registering model and modelAdmin

Tags: django

I am trying to register the models I have made for my project.. while running it gives me the error "name 'rj_rootAdmin' is not defined" I am trying to register the model and the modelAdmin class. It works when i don't register modelAdmin it works. please help me where I am wrong. There is no problem with TopologyAdmin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from Input.models import Topology, rj_root 

class TopologyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Info',                    {'fields': ['Physical_id','Date','User'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
        ('Link_start Information', {'fields': ['Start_node','Start_port'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
        ('Link_end Information',    {'fields': ['End_node','End_port'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
        ('Data',                    {'fields': ['Stm_type','Technology','Status'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
                ]
class rj_rootAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [   
        ('Info',                   {'fields': ['Date','User','Path_id','Service_type','User_label'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
        ('Link Information',       {'fields': ['Source_node','Source_port','Destination_node','Destination_port'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
        ('Link Details',           {'fields': ['Working_state','Service_rate','Protection','Card','Port','K','L','M'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
        ('Intermediate link info', {'fields': ['I1_node','I1_port','I2_node','I2_port','I3_node','I3_port','I4_node','I4_port','I5_node', 'I5_port', 'I6_node','I6_port','I7_node','I7_port','I8_node','I8_port','I9_node','I9_port','I10_port','I10_port','I11_node','I11_port','I12_node', 'I12_port', 'I13_node','I13_port','I14_node','I14_port','I15_node','I15_port','I16_node','I16_port','I17_node','I17_port','I18_node','I18_port','I19_node', 'I19_port','I20_node','I20_port','I21_node','I21_port','I22_node','I22_port','I23_node','I23_port','I24_node','I24_port','I25_node', 'I25_port'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
] 
    admin.site.register(Topology, TopologyAdmin)
    admin.site.register(rj_root, rj_rootAdmin )
```

Comment: Have you checked your indentation? It's not correct in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You have indentation problems. The last two lines need to be moved all the way to the left. As they are now, they are inside the rj_rootAdmin class, and a class name isn't visible inside its own definition.